# Can I Make a foreignKey to same model in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Assume I have this model :

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
```

Now I would like that a task may be relates to another task. So I wanted to do this :

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    relates_to = ForeignKey(Task)
```

however I have an error which states that Task is note defined.
Is this "legal" , if not, how should I do something similar to that ?

Comment: If you don't want `relates_to` to link to itself, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/37946885/247696

Answer (score 168, accepted):

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    relates_to = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: Good idea with using `self` instead of 'Task'!

Comment: Suppose I use something like this and want to delete Tasks. Since each Task instance has a foreignkey to another Task instance, if I delete one Task instance will Django automatically cascade deletes so it auto deletes any Task instance that points to the Task I just deleted? In other words, does CASCADE DELETE still work within the same model?

Comment: @Marc I haven't confirmed specifically, but that would be the behavior I expect. With Django, I'm more worried about specifically having to prevent the cascading delete than ensuring it happens.

Comment: Yes you can write it as `models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` to ensure CASCADE DELETE behavior.

Answer (score 22):

Yea you can do that, make the ForeignKey attribute a string:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    relates_to = ForeignKey(to='Task')
```

In depth, you can also cross reference an app's model by using the dot notation, e.g.

```
class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    relates_to = ForeignKey(to='<app_name>.Task')  # e.g. 'auth.User'
```

Comment: I think this syntax has since changed to "models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)"

Comment: @Brendan, I don't think it has, although it is probably best practice to make the side effects explicit.