# Can I make a dynamc number of foreign keys to a single (self) django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm currently creating an equipment management database and need to allow equipment to be associated with other equipment.

Thanks to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214175/can-i-make-a-foreignkey-to-same-model-in-django) I currently have something akin to the following (vastly simplified):

```
class Equipment(models.Model):
    equipment_title = models.CharField()
    relates_to = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

However, to relate a dynamic number of equipment to other equipment I think I need something like a one-to-many field that doesn't exist natively within Django, e.g. a filter housing may be associated with many filter units, and several filter housings may be associated with a machine tool.

How can I get around this? I'm not sure that it's the right place for a many-to-many field...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ForeignKey *is* a one-to-many relationship, defined on the "many" side. Since your relationship is pointing to self anyway, it already does what you want.