# Django: Add foreign key in same model but different class

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I'm new to Django. How to add foreign key in same Model of different class?

```
from django.db import models

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Player(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        self.Student, #?
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )
    sports_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need use `self`, just leave only class name `Student`:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        Student,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )
    sports_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Use `self` in case you need to get attribute of current instance: `self.some_attribute`, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self) for more details.

Also you can pass model name as the string:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(
        'Student',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )
    sports_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

It's called [lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#lazy-relationships) relationship and usefull when related model is not defined yet.

Comment: OK. this should work. I thought I have to use Django's Generic Relations

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to use self.Student.Use this

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Player(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(self.Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    sports_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Don't forget to use

> python manage.py makemigrations and python manage.py migrate

after you had done changes in model.

In some point -in-time you might want to use same model to have ForeignKey field. For that you may use self or the current model you want to make it as a Foreign Key('self' or 'Player') as string

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(models.CharField(max_length=20))
    address = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    related_student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete = models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

For this Example you may refer. 
[Can I Make a foreignKey to same model in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214175/can-i-make-a-foreignkey-to-same-model-in-django)