# Why is Django giving me a ValueError when I reference a class within the same model?

Tags: python, django, database, class, model

I'm building a simple recipe app, and so far I have two models: `Ingredient` and `Recipe`.

Each recipe should have multiple ingredients, so I laid out my model like this:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ingredients = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=CASCADE)
    instructions = JSONField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=SET_DEFAULT, default='Chef Anon')
```

When I makemigrations, I get nothing, but when I migrate, I get this ValueError:

`ValueError: Cannot alter field cookbook.Recipe.ingredients into cookbook.Recipe.ingredients - they do not properly define db_type (are you using a badly-written custom field?)`

Following the example here ([Django: Add foreign key in same model but different class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49484971/django-add-foreign-key-in-same-model-but-different-class)), I've tried setting `ingredients=models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, on_delete=CASCADE)` as well as using lazy syntax `ingredients=models.ForeignKey("Ingredient", on_delete=CASCADE)`, but each time, `makemigrations` shows no changes, and `migrate` gives me the same `ValueError`.

*Edit*
My imports:

````
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE, SET_DEFAULT, SET_NULL
from django.db.models.fields.json import JSONField
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `on_delete=CASCADE` with `on_delete=models.CASCADE`

If you have not imported `CASCADE` separately from `models`.

All though, in that case you should get a warning that "CASCADE is not defined".

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include my imports at the top:
`from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE`

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem: My `models.py` file was in the root directory, not in the app directory.